# Keep the rows belonging to the largest group only in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['pt1','px1','t95','sx1','dc4', 'px5'],
'feature':['f7','f7', 'f7','f8','f8', 's1'],
'score':['2','3.3','4','8','4.9', '6']})
```

I want to:
 1- compute group size for each group in column "feature"
(result would be f7: 3;  f8: 2; s1:1)
 2- find the max group size (which is f7: 3)
 3- keep the rows that belong to the group with max size (f7) and remove the rest of the rows

The final pd.DataFrame would be:

```
id feature score
pt1   f7      2
px1   f7     3.3
t95   f7      4
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` + `tranform` with `count`, along with an additional filtering step:

```
v = df.groupby('feature').feature.transform('count')
df[v.eq(v.max())]

    id feature score
0  pt1      f7     2
1  px1      f7   3.3
2  t95      f7     4
```

Comment: @SaNa Something like `df[v.eq(v.max())].to_excel('file.xls')` should hopefully be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need the group size, you can do simpler without `groupby`.

Find the most frequent group then filter by that group:

```
df.loc[df['feature'] == df['feature'].mode()[0]]

  feature   id score
0      f7  pt1     2
1      f7  px1   3.3
2      f7  t95     4
```

BTW, if you want to get the group size, you can just do

```
df.groupby('feature')['feature'].count()
```